# What effect does the Searchmaton's energy beam have on humans?

Tags: dennou-coil

In the anime Den-noh Coil the Searchmaton frequently fire their energy beams on humans.

The beams are designed to effect digital matter, and rogue AR programs, but the human characters act as though they are also harmful to them and react as if they were being shot at by a laser beam.

Other than damaging any technology that they have on them, do the Searchmaton energy beams have any actual effects on humans, and if so, what is the effect?

Please limit answers to effects that are addressed in franchise canon, and cite the episode numbers/titles where the information is drawn from, and not fan speculation or fan-fiction.